# Arrays, SUM + INDEX/MATCH

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets

[image]

Note: tried in Excel and Google Sheets, but I have a preference for Sheets.

Basically I want to get the sum of a group of data using `INDEX` and `MATCH` (because the parameters are going to be drop-down dependent):

[image]

The desired result is:

[image]

So this will require a few things:

> 1. Converting the cell D13(April) to a Month
> 2. Converting the "weekof" column to a Month
> 3. Using INDEX and MATCH and MATCH again, I'm assuming because it's multiple cell references.

Here's my solution currently below:

```
=SUM(INDEX(D5:I9, MATCH(MONTH(D13&1),ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH(C5:C9)),0), MATCH(E12,D4:I4,0)))
```

This returns the NEAREST value:

```
270
```

Instead of:

```
804
```

Why this value?

```
270+500+34 = 804
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not strict to use INDEX and MATCH, you may use the following solution:

Add extra column name it "Month", this column will extract the month name from the date column using TEXT function as the following:

```
=IF(C3<>"",TEXT(C3,"mmmm"),"")
```

The if statements ensures that only filled dates will have a month value, since you have to fill this column with the above formula for a certain amount of cells.

Now you can simply use the SUMIF function in cell E13 or where ever you want:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,D13,D:D)
```

[image]
If you don't want the Month column to appear within your data table you may put it at the end of your table and hide it.

Comment: This is a good call. But how would I think achieve drop-down dependency based on the column?

Comment: '''=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(B:B,D13,INDEX(D4:I9,ARRAYFORMULA(4:9),MATCH(E12,D4:I4,0))'''

that's my attempt, but it's not working

Comment: Do you mean that drop down list should contain only the months listed in the date column? Not all months from jan to dec

Comment: either works. I can get the months part, but it's the individual column metrics (count1, favorites, etc) that I can't get

Comment: You are welcome.  Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use `FILTER` then `SUM` the result instead to simplify your formula to this one:

#### Formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER(D:D, TEXT(C:C,"MMMM") = E13))
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### UPDATE:

- The above formula should also update when the value is dropdown. Dropdown is just data that can be changed with predetermined values, aside from that, it should be the same when using a normal cell.
- To match columns, use `MATCH` and `INDEX` together with the formula above. See modified formula below.
- Be careful of the circular dependency. make sure your ranges doesn't interfere with the actual cell where you put your formula.

#### Column Matching:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(D:E, TEXT(C:C, "MMMM") = E13),,MATCH(F12, D4:4, 0)))
```

[image: output2]

Comment: But this doesn't achieve drop-down dependency? My issue is I'd like colleagues to be able to select the month and the column

Comment: using a dropdown for the month should still work. But for the column, I wasn't able to include it. Will try to modify it for the column part using filter, will have to combine it with index and match i believe

Comment: @clucko87, I have modified the above formula, see for the dropdown values of month and columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table and group dates by year and month.